# How can i replace one image on a newly created image with python gimp?

Tags: python, scripting, gimp

i'm trying to replace a newly created image with an image from my filesystem in gimp

```
from gimpfu import *
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()

graphic = pdb.gimp_file_load(cwd + '/original.psd', cwd + '/original.psd')

# image where i'm going to replace the graphic
image = gimp.Image()

pdb.gimp_file_save(graphic, graphic.layers[0], cwd + '/test.png', '?')
```

i don't find anything helpful on the documentation, thanks for any help/guidance you can provide me

Comment: What you want isn't clear... If you want to replace an image by another one you just do a file copy, or if you want to replace it with a source in a another format, then using ImageMagick's `convert` it can be as simple as `convert original.psd test.png`. So why makes your want to use Gimp instead? In you code `gimp. Image()` just creates an empty image, what are you going to replace in it? PS: by definition of the CWD, `cwd+'/file'` and `'file'` are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

i found out that you can use

```
pdb.gimp_image_insert_layer(image, graphic, image.layers[0], 0)
```

i hope it helps someone.

if you dig into gimp documentation from python console you will find a lot more info than digging the official doc